# Search a word in the given string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have to find `subtext` in `text` without using builtin function of `string`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string subtext = "polly";
  string text = "polly put the katle on,polly put the katle on,polly put the katle on,we all have tea";
  int i, j, found;
  int strLen, wordLen;
  strLen = text.Length;
  wordLen = subtext.Length;
  for (i = 0; i < strLen - wordLen; i++)
  {
    found = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < wordLen; j++)
    {
      if (text[i + j] != subtext[j])
      {
        found = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found == 1)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(" found at index:", subtext, i);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are not allowed IndexOf, or Contains or SubString? Is it a code review question?

Comment: can `.Split` be used?

Comment: @GabrielLlorico that's a good one there :)

Comment: Since this looks like homework i'm not giving to much info. But your console write seems wrong. Try `Console.WriteLine($"{subtext} found at index: {i}");` instead. With the info that lines gives you should be able to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how long you would like to search, your current code seems to find all indexes (or at least that seems to be the intent)

Some things you could change however is instead of always starting the loop, you could validate the if the char at position `i` matches the first char of the subtext, and if not continue.

When you want to write the data to the console, don't forget to add the spaceholders for your arguments, like:

```
Console.WriteLine("found {0} at index: {1}", subtext, i);
```

For the rest, I guess your current implementation is okay, but you could add some validations, like ensuring that both texts are available, and if subtext is longer than the text, simply return -1 directly.

For a simple find of first index, I wrote this one up, it still looks pretty similar to yours

```
private static int FindIn( string text, string sub ) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( text ) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( sub ) ) {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( sub ) ? 0 : -1;
    }
    if (text.Length < sub.Length) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - sub.Length; i++) {
        if (text[i] != sub[0]) {
            continue;
        }
        var matched = true;
        for (int j = 1; j < sub.Length && i + j < text.Length; j++) {
            if (text[i+j] != sub[j]) {
                matched = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matched) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Which you can play around with [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VaQj9F)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of pattern-matching algorithms in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), i will leave here c# implementation of Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm.

```
static int[] GetPrefix(string s)
{
    int[] result = new int[s.Length];
    result[0] = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        while (index >= 0 && s[index] != s[i]) { index--; }
        index++;
        result[i] = index;
    }

    return result;
}

static int FindSubstring(string pattern, string text)
{
    int res = -1;
    int[] pf = GetPrefix(pattern);
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        while (index > 0 && pattern[index] != text[i]) { index = pf[index - 1]; }
        if (pattern[index] == text[i]) index++;
        if (index == pattern.Length)
        {
            return res = i - index + 1;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all occurance of the subtect in the text you can use the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string subtext = "polly";
    string text = "polly put the katle on,polly put the katle on,polly put the katle on,we all have tea";
    int index = 0;
    int startPosition = 0;
    bool found = false;

    while (index < text.Length - 1)
    {
        if (subtext[0] == text[index])
        {
            startPosition = index;
            index++;
            for (int j = 1; j <= subtext.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (subtext[j] != text[index])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} found at index: {1}", subtext, startPosition);
            found = false;
        }
        index++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you are looking only for the first occurance add break in the "if (found)" condition